# Changing column type based on another column in Jquery JTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

I have the following JQuery JTable fields

```
id: {
    //...
},
displayName: {
    //...
},
defaultAvailable: {
   //...
},
elementValues: {
    //...
    //dependsOn: displayName
}
formCreated: function (event, data) {
    var availableRules = [];
    //...
    data.form.find('[name=displayName]').autocomplete({
        source: availableRules
    });
}
```

displayName field is an autocomplete field. I need to change the display type of elementValues field based on the value selected for displayName.

Is it possible to use dependsOn?

Is there any possible way to implement this?

Thanks in advance..